# Update com dois model Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Estou estudando sobre o Yii2 e não possuo muito conhecimento do framework.

Estou com dificuldade para atualizar dados no banco que estão em dois models diferentes (Aluno e Endereco).

A ideia é simples, carregar a view com os dados do aluno (que possui o endereço também, porém existe um model só de endereço).

Update do Aluno (Controller) :

```
public function actionUpdate($id){
        $model = $this->findModel($id);        

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);      
}
```

No model Aluno tenho o seguinte método:

```
public function getEndereco0(){
        return $this->hasOne(Enderecos::className(), ['id' => 'endereco']);
}
```

Imagem do EER:

[image: ERR]

O create está pegando certinho. Só estou com essa dúvida no update, quem chamar, como, onde e etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa ter os dois models no seu formulário de Update (Aluno e Endereço), e no controller buscar o Aluno, e após o aluno, buscar o Endereço usando a chave estrangeira que estará na tabela Aluno:

Retirei este exemplo da [documentação](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-multiple-models):

**Controller**

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\Profile;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
    $user = User::findOne($id);
    if (!$user) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The user was not found.");
    }

    $profile = Profile::findOne($user->profile_id);

    if (!$profile) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The user has no profile.");
    }

    $user->scenario = 'update';
    $profile->scenario = 'update';

    if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $profile 
     ->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $isValid = $user->validate();
        $isValid = $profile->validate() && $isValid;
        if ($isValid) {
            $user->save(false);
            $profile->save(false);
            return $this->redirect(['user/view', 'id' => $id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'user' => $user,
        'profile' => $profile,
    ]);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'user-update-form',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($user, 'username') ?>

    ...other input fields...

    <?= $form->field($profile, 'website') ?>

    <?= Html::submitButton('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Comment: Sim, exatamente! Eu tinha conseguido e esquecido da pergunta aqui rsrs mas está correto. Obg cara!